# How to send a javascript response from server without escaping characters in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, ckeditor

Hi i am using CKEditor in my laravel application  .  i am browsing my computer and upload images to server .

using this code

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'messageArea',{
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/newseditor/imageupload'
});
```

after i submit the image i need to send the response back to my html page .i am doing it like this

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>"`;

but it is not executing it as a javascript function . in my source i can see it as

```
"&lt;script type='text\/javascript'&gt;window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(204, 'test\/test', '');&lt;\/script&gt;"
```

so the special characters are escaped :( . I tried to use

```
htmlspecialchars_decode
htmlspecialchars_encode
json_decode
json_encode
```

but still i cannot trigger it as a js function  , is there anyway i can achieve this .

Thank you ...

**UPDATE**

this is the tutorial i am following

http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

Comment: I don't think there is any way that *special chars* are encoded on its own!

Comment: write the content to a hidden div , then read it from there. it may help

Comment: @RayonDabre hi i think it is doneby the Laravel framework

Comment: must you use echo ? are you doing this in a blade template?

Comment: use .append function of js ?

Comment: @JobinJose is right! Use hidden input field and keep `script` initialization out of `echo`!

Comment: hey no , this response is for set the URL field in CKeditor , i only have to trigger the CKEditor function in this case and CKEditor will handle the rest . the problem is my javascript is not getting triggered because they are escaped

Comment: @RayonDabre , Hi i don't have any control of this because i am using CKEdtor filebrowserUploadUrl function . I cannot catch the susses event of that , only i can call callFunction() with the parameters in response, i don't have any control of this , that is the problem , check this http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was not able to pass JS from the server  . so i did a simple work around using jQuery .  I will catch the response using jQuery and manually add it to the URL field . Up to now this works as expected , hope this helps to anyone . thanks .

i am using the click event of image submit button .

```
$(document).on('click',".cke_dialog_ui_button",function() {

        var element = $(this).closest("tr").prev();
        element.find("iframe").hide();

        var checkExist = setInterval(function() {

           var url_container = element.find("iframe").contents().find("body pre");
           if ((typeof url_container != 'undefined') && (url_container.length > 0)) {

              var url = $.trim(url_container.html());
              url = url.replace(/[\\"]+/g,'');

              if(url.length > 0)
              {
                  url_container.html("");
                  $(".cke_dialog_page_contents:first").find("table tbody tr:first").find(":text").val(url);               
              }

              element.find("iframe").show();
              clearInterval(checkExist);

           }
        }, 200);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unsure if your using blade,**

but in the event you are using it the syntax for not escaping out characters is {!! $name !!}

I'd also try var_dump to insure the problem isn't in the ckeditor formatting.

Config settings for disabling ckeditor html formatting:

```
config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;
config.entities = false;
```

Docs:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.basicEntities